# Vertical line with pointed bottom end in CSS

Tags: css, border, line, shapes, css-shapes

Just a quick question:

How can I create this vertical shape in CSS?

This is going to be a left border of a div.

Many thanks!

***UPDATE***
The main issue is with the bottom part of the line.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `border-left` on your `div`.

Comment: @PaulDraper I thinks the main issue is with the bottom part of the border, which I believe OP wants to be diagonal

Comment: If @RaulRene is correct, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yeah the main issue is the bottom part ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this trick with borders:

```
div {
  border-left:20px solid orange;
  border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
  width:0;
  height:300px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeRL4/17/)

Comment: border-top isnt required, height controls the vertical dimension anyways right?

Answer (score 2):

Working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/F25zD/

CSS Rules

```
div{
  height:100px;
  width:0px;
  border-left:5px solid #aa0;
  border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a `<div>` you could use this css:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-left: 10px solid gold;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2Zuu/)

For a 45° angle on the bottom, the `border-bottom` must be the same as the `border-left`. To alter the angle, change the width of `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with after pseudo element but this is another way:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="line"></div>

</div>



.top {
height:20px;
background-color:#f0ae3f;
width:20px;
}
.line {
height:300px;
background-color:#f0ae3f;
width:20px;
-moz-transform: skewX(0deg) skewY(-40deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(0deg) skewY(-40deg);
-o-transform: skewX(0deg) skewY(-40deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(0deg) skewY(-40deg);
transform: skewX(0deg) skewY(-40deg);
margin-top:-10px;
}
```

here you have the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/WgmmU/1/

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look at doing this using the `:after` selector in css

HTML

```
<div id="vLine"></div>
```

CSS

```
#vLine{
    /* test styling */
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:100px;
    /* end test styling */
    height:100px;
    width:10px;
    background:orange;
}
#vLine:after{
    content: " ";
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 5px; /* half the width of your line*/
    border-top-color: orange; /* because you want to touch the top with color */
    border-left-color: orange; /* because you want to touch the left with color */
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nQKR4/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  background-color:orange;
  width:20px;
  height:300px;
 }
```

Best practice is not to use borders at all, because diffrent browsers render them diffrently (IE). Sometimes it may even break your layouts.

Comment: have you heard of box-sizing and valid doctype ? :)

Comment: have you heard about Internet Explorer and technical debit, that it has ?

Comment: then it's about quirks mode, missing a valid doctype or header of document misswritten , there's this awfull haslayout or not in olders IE, i do not miss IE6 at all, but this was a good coach for CSS learners